# Using the RES command line parameter with the ajaxmin task

Tags: microsoft-ajax-minifier, ajaxmin

How do I use the RES switch in the *Ajaxmin*  *MSBuild* task? I had trouble doing it, even though I got it working in command line. I'm guessing that I'm using the wrong syntax.
This is what I use in command line:

```
ajaxmin.exe Combined.min.js -RES:Strings Strings.resx -o test.min.js
```

What would be the *Ajaxmin* task equivalent for this?

This is what I tried and it doesn't work:

```
AjaxMin Switches="-RES:Strings Strings.resx" JsSourceFiles="Combined.min.js" JsCombinedFileName="test.min.js" /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it right -- you found a bug in the AjaxMin build task. I'll get it fixed for the next version, 4.69.